# Proof of Wigner-Eckart Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wigner-eckart

During my class we've proven the [Wigner-Eckart Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem?oldformat=true) for irreducible tensor operators. However the proof given to the class by our teacher seems to miss something to actually complete the proof. I might've missed it or it might be trivial, but I couldn't understand it on my own or find a similar proof. The general idea is very similar to what's written in the last page of this [file](https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Courses/QuantumMechanicsForOptics/WignerEckart.pdf).

We start by defining this set of vectors:

$ |\sigma,j'',m''\rangle = \sum_{m'q} T_q^k|\alpha',j',m'\rangle \langle j',m';k,q | j'',m'' \rangle $

We then prove, as the notation suggests, that this is an eigenvector of $J^2,J_z$ (by verifying that the action of $J_{\pm},J_z$ is the same) and thus:

$ \langle\alpha,j,m | \sigma,j',m' \rangle \propto \delta_{jj'}\delta_{mm'} $

We then prove, using the recursion relations of the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, that:

$ \langle \alpha,j,m |T_q^k | \alpha',j,m' \rangle = \langle \alpha,j,m| \sigma,j,m \rangle \langle j',m';k,q | j,m \rangle$

What's missing (or at least what I've missed) is proving that the first term in the above product is in fact independent of $m$ (which is what makes the Wigner-Eckart Theorem really useful):

$ \langle \alpha,j,m| \sigma,j,m \rangle = \langle \alpha,j,j| \sigma,j,j \rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{2j+1}} \langle\alpha,j||T^k||\alpha',j',\rangle$

If anything is not clear I'll try to explain it better. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I understand that you wish to understand you teacher's exposition, but what other textbooks did you read and compare proofs to?

Comment: which first term in which above product?

Comment: @DanielC I've read the proof on Sakurai and a few other sources online, but I didn't actually follow through all of details, since I was interested in this particular proof.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I've specified which term I meant.

Comment: You might want to check out the first sort of proof of the WE theorem in Georgi's book

Comment: I've read through it, but it uses such a different approach to what I've used so far that I can't really follow it (I really don't know how to go about doing the "highest weight analysis" and how it leads to the coefficients $k_J$ being indepndent of $m$).

Comment: The highest weight procedure is just the standard procedure of constructing states using ladder operators. Once you know one state, you can construct all the others using ladder operators

Comment: I know how to construct the states using ladder operators, but not how to use this in practice to get the result cited in the book. I thought about doing something like this, but it seems unnecessary since I've already used the ladder operators in my teacher's proof.